# After reloading CN1 Form, GUI elements stop working properly

Tags: codenameone

Our app allows users to submit data to our servers.

Sometimes, users will need to make 3 submission in a row. After checking that the submission works properly (and thankfully it does), we call `CustomForm().show()` and the `Form` shows correctly. (CustomForm obviously extends Form.)

We use `InteractionDialog`s, just as in all other iterations, to handle validation by providing feedback to the user. We do so to mimic the Android Snackbar that provides a prompt and a Button to do an action. In the 1st 2 iterations, the `InteractionDialog`s show and dispose properly; in the 3rd iteration, the `InteractionDialog`s start acting erratically.

We also noticed that once that `CustomForm` (or any other submission forms)  is shown 3 times (either the same `Form` 3 times in a row, or any combo of our submission forms 3 times altogether), a different Form displaying a `BrowserComponent` will fail – the `BrowserComponent` will not show anything at all, despite using a strong, unfiltered internet connection and having worked properly prior to the submissions being done. Neither the app nor the `Form` housing the `BrowserComponent` crashes -- the `BrowserComponent` simply does not show anything.

Is there a limit on how many instances of a given `Form` can be shown, or is there a memory issue?

Please, any ideas on how to solve this?

Thank you.

**EDIT**: I am adding a screenshot of the EDT thread -- it seems to have `invokeAndBlock()` called twice and then `wait()` is called, even though I wrapped my call to show the `Form` with the `BrowserComponent` with this `try-catch`:

```
try {
    CN.invokeWithoutBlocking(() -> {
       new FormWithBrowser().show();
    )};
} catch (BlockingDisallowedException ex) {
   e.getMessage();
}
```

[image]

The other issue is how do I fix `InteractionDialog`s in my submission form from being affected by `invokeAndBlock()` and `wait()` as well? I also don't get any `BlockingDisallowedException`s in my logs. Does that mean that `wait()` is really the issue?

Thanks again.

Comment: Can you pause the debugger and add the stack trace of the EDT to your question?

Comment: Thank you. At which point should I pause the debugger? After the 2nd submission, the call to open the Form with the BrowserComponent, etc.?

Comment: When it's slow or stuck

Comment: Thanks @Shai Almog. Added the stack trace to my now-edited question.

Comment: This stack should release the invokeAndBlock within a few seconds. Are there other calls to that API?

Comment: No, the app just waits, it's not frozen, but nothing happens in that form.

Comment: We're looking into this. It might be a regression in the FX port. That's probably not as crucial as it shouldn't happen once the CEF migration is in

Comment: I have just run a series of tests on JDK8 and JDK11 and can't seem to reproduce this issue.  Probably best to file an issue in the issue tracker and provide a self-contained test case so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I was able to solve this by calling my InteractionDialogs with showModeless(). I got the idea from Lianna.